# How to make condition works if an element doesn't have a specific class, in my case "active"?

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzamA.png)I have many items: a, b, c, d, e, f  When I click on item b, I add class "active" on this and remove that class on the other elements, the fact is when the class is active is detected, I want the background to change according to the element else if it doesn't have the class I want to put a different picture.

```
/*  on click on b */
$("#item-b").click(function() {

    $("#content-a,#content-c,#content-d,#content-e,#content-f").hide();
    $("#content-b").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#content-b").show();
    $("#item-b").addClass("active");
    event.preventDefault();


});

if ($("#item-b").hasClass("active")) {
    $('#img-b').attr('src', 'img/img-b-active.png'); /* change  icon*/
    $('.section-grey').css("background-image", "url(img/bg-ateliers-cuisine.png)"); /* changer background*/
    $('#btn-offre').css("background-color", "#ffbf4a"); /* changer bouton color*/
} else {
    alert("no class active"); /* I want to put another picture here*/
}
```

Comment: Put `if - else` statement into `click` method

Comment: I tried before and it works only with the background and the picture, but the else  with the alert doesn't work when the "active" is removed on this item when I click on another item like c

Comment: do you want to change the background by clicking on different elements like buttons? like different backgrounds on clicking different buttons?

Comment: the items are  icons, so when I click on item b for exemple it ads a class active on it, then it should change the background-color, the item icon  . but when the class "active" is removed from item-b I want to set another kind of icon.  Even the "no class active" doesn't work when the class  is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of CSS and jQuery to achieve this. 
I suggest you add some common classes to the items ( icons ) so you can selected them more easily.

Your CSS can have default values and in your jQuery conditionals just change that default state . Default is not active and in jQuery just change values in case of active. This is if you want to change the src of an image. For colors and other stuf, you can use CSS. Just add the styles under a `.active` class.

See below

the code is pretty straight forward. If you need a detailed explanation please let me know. And also maybe i didn't understand your question correctly. Just tell me in the comments below

```js
$(".item").click(function(event) {

  const otherContent = $(this).siblings().children()
  const thisContent = $(this).children();
  event.preventDefault();
  
  otherContent.hide()
  $(thisContent).removeClass("hidden").show()
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active')
  
  
  if (  $(this).is("#item-a")) {
   // do stuff here
    thisContent.css('color', 'pink')
  } else if (  $(this).is("#item-b")) {
   // do stuff here
    thisContent.css('color', 'green')
  } else if (  $(this).is("#item-c")) {
   // do stuff here
    thisContent.css('color', 'purple')
  }
  
});
```

```css
.item {
  /* no active class */
  background: red;
}

.item.active {
  /* with active class */
  background: blue;
}

.item > div {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item-a" class="item">
  iconA
  <div id="content-a">
    content A
  </div>
</div>
<div id="item-b" class="item">
  iconB
  <div id="content-b">
    content B
  </div>
</div>
<div id="item-c" class="item">
  iconC
  <div id="content-c">
    content C
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I put , i added a picture on top of the question. item-b is an icon off , put it should change to a (on) version of the picture it when it has the class ("active)

Comment: Yes. Just change the src of the image in the  `if (  $(this).is("#item-b")) {
   // do stuff here }` condition. Simple as that

Comment: @AinaRaharison i didn't do your exact code 100% . You just need to add the specific things yourself inside the logic

Comment: yes, i understand what yout did. all my default pictures are declared on my HTML inside links <a >. I will try your method and I will tell you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can make condition work if there is no particular class or you can add class. please refer the below code.

> i have used jquery and css to explain this issue.

```js
$('.det').on('click',function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
$(this).removeClass('active');
}else{
$(this).addClass('active');
}
})
```

```css
.active{
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="det">click here again and again</div>

<div class='det'>click here again and again</div>
```